# What is the name for 'cheating' with data, i.e. letting machine learning models use out-of-sample data?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, data

What is the term for abusing data and machine learning methods to get better results than normally (with proper training and test set)? Some of my co-workers call it data-mining but I do not believe that is the correct word?

Comment: [Leakage](https://machinelearningmastery.com/data-leakage-machine-learning/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the word: data snooping